# How to format more variables in Bash and take it in same .txt file with expect order?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, command

I'm trying to solve one challenge in Bash. I have quite a few .txt files with registration data. I want to make a new .txt file, to store new registered users day-by-day, and at the end of the file in new line the total number of users.

My script is already working nearly in the correct way (in the view of result), and I've tried to solve it with a different bracket or take the data to the variable.

Anyway, this is my script:

```
route_from=/route/*
saved=daily_registrations.txt
var1=Total_registrations:

cat $route_from | cut -f1,2 -d' ' | sort -V | uniq -c > /route/$saved #Cuts New users number | file number | date
echo $var1 >> /route/$saved #"Total_registrations:"
cat $route_from | wc -l >> /route/$saved #Total user number
```

I expect the output result like this in the .txt file ( I take the vertical bars only for a better view).

```
New users number | file number | date
New users number | file number | date
New users number | file number | date
Total_registrations: number
```

But now my actual output looks like this:

```
New users number | file number | date
New users number | file number | date
New users number | file number | date
Total_registrations: 
number
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last two lines each give an output which is directed to file, by nature of bash they are both written on a seperate line.
I suggest you combine them to output both at once, using a subshell for the calculation of the lines:

```
echo $var1 $(cat $route_from | wc -l) >> /route/$saved
```

or

```
echo $var1 `cat $route_from | wc -l` >> /route/$saved
```

This should write the contents of `$var` as well as the number of lines in your file using the same echo command.

Apart from that, it is better to not `cat` the file aand pipe it through the `wc` command, this can be done using a redirect as such:

```
wc -l < $route_from
```

For a file of around 500 lines on my system and 1000 runs it is a little faster:

```
[user@host ~]$
 time for i in `seq 1000`; do cat $route_from | wc -l > /dev/null; done

real    0m2.480s
user    0m0.814s
sys     0m1.783s
[user@host ~]$ time for i in `seq 1000`; do wc -l < $route_from > /dev/null; done

real    0m1.971s
user    0m0.537s
sys     0m0.855s
[user@host ~]$
```

Thus I would do it like this:

```
echo $var1 `wc -l < $route_from` >> /route/$saved
```

Comment: It's super useful, thank you for your very specified answer! The database contains now more than 150000 lines, so every little time, what the system can win in time better than nothing, and also helps me to write a better script in next time. :)

Comment: I tried your suggested code line, but the system writes an ambiguous redirect error. All other versions are working well.

Comment: Yeah, the thing after `<` needs to be a single file, not a wildcard.

Comment: So that's the problem, with that, because now I have more than 180 days data in files, and it's counting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've written a POSIX awk solution.

```
awk -v OFS=' | ' '
  {
    Regs[$1 OFS $2]++
    total++
  } 
  END {
    for(reg in Regs) print Regs[reg], reg
    print "Total: " total
  }
' /route/* |sort -V >/route/daily_registrations
```

`OFS`: Output Field Separator

`R[$1 OFS $2]++`: Increment an array whose index is the first two columns, separated by `|`.

`END{...}`: Precede each index by the increment, then print total.

Comment: Thanks :). I don't understand this in all the way, but I will figure out how it's works :).

Answer (score 0):

Replace the last 2 lines as:

```
echo -e "$var1 \c" >> /route/$saved #"Total_registrations:"
cat $route_from | wc -l >> /route/$saved #Total user number
```

`\c` will ensure that newline character is not appended and the next appends happens from there

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and clarification, it's working now.

Comment: `echo -e` is poorly portable and the `\c` escape even more so, as well as IMHO unappealing and surprising. The portable way to do this is with `printf`